# In Bayesian parameter estimation, prior update involves averaging posteriors of all examples?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I was reading Andriy Burkov's the hundred page machine learning book (section 2.5, check here: http://themlbook.com/wiki/doku.php)

I am a little bit confused by the way he computes the prior for the next iteration, which is highlighted in the screenshot below. In my understanding bayesian update should be incremental and the prior for the next iteration should just be the posterior that you derived from the current example, isn't it? The author seems to be computing the posteriors for all examples and averaging them in every iteration. Something I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: Sadly, no.  I would not trust this source for anything after reading this excerpt.  There are a lot of red flags here, and you've found one of them.   Note also the contradiction between the highlighted definition and equation (5), which is also wrong, as, with that formulation, the prior is included in the product $N$ times.

Comment: I don't see something wrong with those notes. The highlighted expression is just the marginal posterior distribution, and he just uses a monte carlo approzimation to the integral of the marginal posterior distribution. As well in the equation five is just the MAP estimate for a single observation. Note it is the same thing if you update posterior iteratively or altogether for all observations.

Comment: Hello Fiodor1234, I believe what the author means is "before updating the posterior again with the next example, we replace the prior in eq.4 by [highlighted part]". In this sense, how does it related to the point you refer to: updating posterior altogether for all observations? It still seems to me that he is about to update it example by example, but in each iteration he uses all observations.